# Assert.DoesNotThrow() for Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I want to assert a test does not throw an exception.

I am using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

I am looking for an equivalent of `Nunit Assert.DoesNotThrow()`

Answer (score 0):

Does not appear to be one.

I resorted to just using `Assert.IsTrue` with description text.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Check_some_statement_DoesNotThrow()
    {
        statement;
        Assert.IsTrue(true, "Expect above statement not to throw");
    }
```